# Crontab won't run bash cript

Tags: scripts, cron

I have a bash script that takes backup of my gitlab server and copies the files to another disk.

The script runs as expected when I run it by hand.

I tried to add it as a job in `crontab` but it doesn't seem to run.

This is how I tried to setup the `crontab`:

`sudo crontab -e`

I set it up to run every day at 12:00.
I tried different times as well, but still no luck.
`0 12 * * * root /home/user/dev/backup.sh`

`sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`

However I do not see any files in the expected directory. If I manually run the script it works fine.

The first line of my script contains `#!/bin/bash` I don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `sudo crontab -e` it is always the crontab of root and there it is a syntax error to add the username. Make sure the script has the executable bit set (`chmod +x /home/user/dev/backup.sh`).

This crontab entry should do it:

```
0 12 * * * /home/user/dev/backup.sh
```

Comment: I was about to answer my own question but, yes that's how it works. Thank you very much!